# How to set jsonObject to java pojo

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want  list of id,name set in java pojo which i return to controller and then use by api.
Here is an example of how json data i want to send back .

```
    {
      "chapterName":sometext,
      "chapterId":1,
      "topic":[{
        "topicId":1,
        "topicName":something }]
    }

I am only maintaing i table for chapter and topic .to get topic i have a column called parent_chapter_topic_id from which i get topic if its not null and contain chapter_id.

so for that i have use below query found from stackoverflow.

    SELECT chapter.chapter_topic_id as id,
                            chapter.topic as name,
                            CASE WHEN count(topic.chapter_topic_id) = 0 THEN null
                            ELSE json_agg(json_build_object('id', topic.chapter_topic_id,
                                                    'name', topic.topic)) END ::text children_text
                            FROM chapter_topic chapter
                            INNER JOIN chapter_topic topic on topic.parent_chapter_topic_id = chapter.chapter_topic_id
                            WHERE chapter.parent_chapter_topic_id IS NULL
                            AND chapter.subject_id = 1
                            AND chapter.grade = '5'
                            AND chapter.client_id = 1
                            AND chapter.delete_user_id is NUll
                            GROUP BY chapter.chapter_topic_id
```

This query return me
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/duDlD.png

As u can check the above query returns text

So what i want is i am using Rowmapper in Dao class to map column data to pojo object ,but i dont know how to map "child_text" column in pojo class .I tried to use Sting data type but it returns me string ,i want json format.which i can use in angular app.

U can check what output i want.

```
   [
  {
    "chapterName" : "Inheritance",
    "chapterId"         : 1,
    "subjectId"          : 1,
    "subjectName"   : "OOPJ",
    "grade"             : 5,
    "clientId"               : 1
    "topic"                    : [
            { 
                "topicId" : 1,
                "topicName": "single",
        
            },
            { 
                "topicId" : 2,
                "topicName": "multiple",
        
            },
  }
```

Comment: This is not an angular issue, Please correctly tag the language you are using.

Comment: Thanks.I have changed can u now help me out